# SQL - Converting a non-standard String to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got some date/time data in a string, in the format '26/10/2009 09:06:43' (i.e. the date is in UK format). When I try

```
SELECT CAST('26/10/2009 09:06:43' AS DATETIME)
```

I get the following error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in
>   an out-of-range datetime value.

I'm sure the solution is really, really simple but every example I can find online seems to overcomplicate things!

I'd appreciate any help you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `convert` function instead providing style number:

```
SELECT convert(DATETIME, '26/10/2009 09:06:43', 103)
```

You can find out all formats here: http://www.sqlhub.com/2009/04/list-of-all-available-datetime-format.html

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a `format` function here at all (it's `CONVERT`), and the third parameter is called `style` (not `format`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I mean convert :)

Comment: Maybe, it's better to give link on msdn? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In oracle it's like that :

```
SELECT to_date('26/10/2009 09:06:43', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

with a following site :

http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date
It's seems to be like this in sql server :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '26/10/2009 09:06:43');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the conversion, set the language to British English:

```
set language [British English]
SELECT CAST('26/10/2009 09:06:43' AS DATETIME)
```

Or you can use the convert function, and declare the style too:

```
SELECT convert(DATETIME, '26/10/2009 09:06:43', 103)
```